# Get an List inside other List in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I'm trying to get an list that in inside an list.

I receive an data from the server as `MutableCollecion` and I change for `List`
[image]

But, as you can see, the list is inside another list. Like, the list `0` is inside the `animeList`. I want to know how can I get the value of the list `0` one by one, if possible.

Here's the code I'm using to get the data from Database:

```
firestoreClient.collection("Users")
            .document(currentUser?.uid ?: "")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val animeList = document.data!!.values.toList()
                println(animeList[0])
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

==================================
I SOLVED IT!!!

```
val animeList = document.data!!.values.toList()
                val s: List<String> = animeList[the position of array you want] as List<String>
```

Comment: In order to provide an answer, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 0'th item via

```
animeList.get(0)
```

And you can loop it like this:

```
val itr = animeList.get(0).listIterator()
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    //Do something with itr.next()
}
```

EDIT

As described in the comment section by Antony, the solution he used was

```
val animeList = document.data!!.values.toList()
val s: List<String> = animeList[0] as List<String> println(s[0])
```

Comment: the listIterator() don't work after the .get(0)

Comment: @AntonyLajes why not? The 0'th element is a list on its own.

Comment: I solved this after 2-3 days! Thanks because your answer make me think in something. Was thas: val animeList = document.data!!.values.toList()
                val s: List<String> = animeList[0] as List<String>
                println(s[0])

Comment: @AntonyLajes thanks for the comment, edited my answer accordingly.